# How to convert ajax code to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

There is a site with some sort of data. Website sends this data via Ajax request from your page. So-called continuous loading of the page. I can login on this site using php. But I can not call from php download these additional pages.

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
  scroll = $(document).scrollTop() + window_height;
  if (scroll > 1500){
            button.fadeIn();
        } else {
            button.fadeOut();
        }

  if(!is_load || !brend) return false;
  document_height =  $(document).height();

  if(document_height - scroll < 1000 && document_height != document_height_prev){
    p = p + 1;
    document_height_prev = document_height;
    var data_send = {
      mode: 'json',
      brend: brend,
      p: p
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/catalog/getObjectsListBrend/',
        data: data_send,
        type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
          if(data.length < 100){
            is_load = false;
          }else{
                    $('div.tovars ul').append(data);
          }
                }
         });
  }
 });
```

Comment: What is the problem at the moment code seems to be okay, except `postfields` part. `$postdata` should be handled with [`http_build_query`](http://ee1.php.net/http_build_query). What is current problem?

Answer (score -2):

if you want sending data to other scripts i recommended use SoapClient and SoapServer for example:

first step make a SoapServer where do you want to get and set data:

```
  $srv = new SoapServer('Your_wsdl');
  $srv->setClass("ServiceClass",$hdr);
  $srv->handle();

  class ServiceClass {
     var $data;

     public function setData($data){
            $this->data = $data; 
     }
  }
```

Second step: make SoapClient where you want send data to SoapServer:

```
     $url = 'Your_wsdl';
     $client     = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
```

and now u can pass into server data like this:

```
     $postData = array(
          'mode' => 'json',
          'brend' => 'zzz',
          'page' => 1
     );
     $client->setData($postData);
```

// in this case your data is set there where you made         SoapServer:

Answer (score -2):

You should formulate your question like a normal person. 
First, the right syntax should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pages/getData/',
    data: { 
        jsarray  : data_send
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){}
});
```

And then in php you just do

```
$php_array = $_POST['jsarray'];
```

And in $php_array you should have it all. And why do you formulate the data type you are about to receive as html when i see from the way you formulated your question it is not... ?
Also ... the correct format of json data is with quotes around the "cell" names, like this :

```
var data_send = {
    'mode': 'json',
    'brend': 'zzz',
    'page': 1
};
```

Comment: I think the question is about making a POST request using PHP, not receiving POST data from an AJAX call.

Comment: To be honest, me neither ;)